# Suggestions for automating Outlook without win32com.client

Tags: python, outlook, outlook-web-app

I'm working with a Python project where I need to fetch email attachments sent to an Exchange account. I understand win32com.client can do what I need, but I need it to work in a Linux environment. I've tried using Mechanize, but it is giving me errors that I can't resolve. (See [Mechanize/OWA user/password error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612539/mechanize-owa-user-password-error))

I suppose I can just use Selenium, but I was hoping to not have to open a browser - just because that is slower and less stable.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx)?